# Make such constraints in Constraint layout that will behave as two LinearLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout with several elements on the left and one, the biggest, on the right. I want to remove items on the left dynamically but they should stay in the center vertically.

Now I achieve it using two `LinearLayout`s:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="horizontal" ...>

  <LinearLayout orientation="vertical" gravity="center_vertical" ...>
    <View first/>
    <View second/>
    <.../>
  </LinearLayout>

  <View theBiggest/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to achieve this behavior using flat `ConstraintLayout` with only one level of hierarchy, without inner layouts?

It looks like this:

[image: Layout schema]

Comment: Ehm, and will it work if I simply use `secondView.setVisibility(GONE)'? Are you sure that you understood the question? I played with Constraint layout and I can't get how to position constraints in a way to achieve this behavior - views should be always centered vertically. Could you please create such layout? Existing answer suggests to change constraints manually but I don't want to do this because then it is simpler to use to Linear Layouts.

Comment: Set visibility to INVISIBLE. IT will take up the space, but will not be visible

Comment: But that's not the thing that I want to get. Look again at the question, please. I want the view to be in center, not in the same place where it was. If you still didn't get the question, look at a proposed answer below and my comment to it.

Comment: By the way, where did you find that I am asking "which is best, A or B"? I ask is it possible because I can't make it to behave this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this functionality through Vertical chaining. Observe two layouts below:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <!--<View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view" />-->

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="160dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

The difference is I have removed the second view and changed the bottom constrain of the first view to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`.
This adjustment of the constraint need to be done dynamically when you are adding and removing view from the left section. You can dynamically add constrain through [ConstraintSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html)

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer, but it looks like it is easier to use LinearLayouts in my case. I have 6 layouts on the left and it is not easy (or worth) to re-make all the constraints manually.